# Handlebars: How to output a field only if it's different between loops using each?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to output something like the following data for an ember js app:

```
- id: 1
  section: section1
  title: my title
- id: 2
  section: section1
  title: ipsum
- id: 3
  section: section2
  title: lorem
```

How can I output the section name only if it changes, i.e. so the template will be something like:

```
{{#each}}
  {{#if section is different to last loop}}{{section}}{{/if}}
  {{title}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Why not compute a list of section without duplicates, and pass that to the template instead ?

Comment: Ditto, easier to do this logic in your controller logic than it is to do in your view logic

Comment: I could preprocess the list but I was hoping handlebars would give me access to the previous item so I could do this directly in the template. If that's the "handlebars way" I guess I'll have to though.